# How to send message through anonymous pipe in c

Tags: c, pipe

I try to use anonymous pipe to send two messages to the parent.  I understand that I need to put the parent into the wait state to let children write the second message then read it from the pipe.  I've tried to use `wait(NULL)` to let the parent wait for the children writing to pipe, but it seems not working. Could somebody help me out? Thanks first.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    #include <unistd.h>  
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    # include <wait.h>  

    #define MaxLen 80
    #define PipeStdIn   0    
    #define PipeStdOut  1   

   int main( ) {
      int ret, myPipes[2];
      char buff[MaxLen + 1];

      if( pipe( myPipes ) == 0 ){

           if( fork( ) == 0 ) {
              char *reply = {"child sends first message.\n"};
              write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], reply, strlen(reply) + 1); 

              char *reply2 = {"child sends second message.\n"};
              write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], reply2, strlen(reply2) + 1); 

       } 
       else { 
              read(myPipes[PipeStdIn], buff, MaxLen); 
              printf("Parent receives message: %s", buff);
              wait(NULL);
              read(myPipes[PipeStdIn], buff, MaxLen);
              printf("Parent receives 2nd message : %s", buff);
       }
     }
      close( myPipes[PipeStdIn] );  
      close( myPipes[PipeStdOut] ); 

      return 0; 
}
```

And this is what I got when I compile it:

```
aaa@ubuntu:~/Desktop/fork$ ./fork
Parent receives message: child sends first message.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the end of the pipe that you don't use within each process:

```
   int main( ) {
      int ret, myPipes[2];
      char buff[MaxLen + 1];

      if( pipe( myPipes ) == 0 ){

           if( fork( ) == 0 ) {
              close (myPipes[PipeStdIn]);
              char *reply = {"child sends first message.\n"};
              write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], reply, strlen(reply) + 1); 

              char *reply2 = {"child sends second message.\n"};
              write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], reply2, strlen(reply2) + 1); 

       } 
       else { 
              close (myPipes[StdOut]);
              read(myPipes[PipeStdIn], buff, MaxLen); 
              printf("Parent receives message: %s", buff);

              read(myPipes[PipeStdIn], buff, MaxLen);
              printf("Parent receives 2nd message : %s", buff);
              wait(NULL);
       }
     }
```

Comment: How can I receive the second message from children?

Comment: Remove the `wait(NULL)` in the middle of the block and put it at the end of it. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Look, it works now, your close() functions were in wrong line. You should close before read or write.

```
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>  

#define MaxLen 80
#define PipeStdIn   0    
#define PipeStdOut  1   

int main( ) {
  int ret, myPipes[2];
  char buff[MaxLen + 1];

  if( pipe( myPipes ) == 0 ){

       if( fork( ) == 0 ) {

          char *reply = {"child sends first message.\n"};

          char *reply2 = {"child sends second message.\n"};

          close(myPipes[PipeStdIn]); // CLOSE BEFORE WRITE
          write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], reply, strlen(reply) + 1); 
          write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], reply2, strlen(reply2) + 1); 

   } 
   else { 

          close(myPipes[PipeStdOut]); // CLOSE BEFORE READ
          read(myPipes[PipeStdIn], buff, MaxLen); 
          printf("Parent receives message: %s", buff);

          read(myPipes[PipeStdIn], buff, MaxLen);
          printf("Parent receives 2nd message : %s", buff);
   }
 }
  return 0; 
 }
```